# NUnit tests not executed

Tags: nunit, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I'm trying to configure TeamCity to run the tests we have.

I created a NUnit Build Step, and I selected these parameters:

Runner type: NUnit
Step name: Tests
Execute step: Only if all previous steps were successful
NUnit runner: NUnit 2.6.1
.NET Runtime: x64, v4.0
Run tests from: 'Tests**\bin\Debug\Tests.*.dll'

The rest is blank.

This is the output in the build log

```
[14:03:31]Step 2/2: Tests (NUnit) (14s)
[14:03:31][Step 2/2] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe #TeamCityImplicit
[14:03:31][Step 2/2] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\743f6358429d804a
[14:03:39][Step 2/2] Start TeamCity NUnit Test Runner
[14:03:39][Step 2/2] Running NUnit-2.6.1 tests under .NET Framework v4.0 x64
[14:03:40][Step 2/2] Tests.Application.XmlImport.dll
[14:03:44][Step 2/2] Start TeamCity NUnit Test Runner
[14:03:44][Step 2/2] Running NUnit-2.6.1 tests under .NET Framework v4.0 x64
[14:03:45][Step 2/2] Tests.Infrastructure.Framework.dll
[14:03:45][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 0
```

To be sure that the tests are not run, each assembly has a Assert.Fail() test.

FYI: the project is using .NET 4.5 and the NUnit assemblies are 2.6.2

Thanks.

Comment: Do the tests run when you invoke them from nunit-console.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very end, I found out that TeamCity wasn't rebuilding the tests and the assemblies were still using the MSTest attributes, hence NUnit couldn't find them.